# Architecture of CNNs

Tags: neural-network, conv-neural-network

I heard the convolution and pooling operations happens in hidden layers but I see the opposite in the picture below....So which one is correct?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/blKnt.png)

Answer (score 0):

Every layer except the input layer (in your case the input image) and the output layer (in your case the final 2-node output layer) can be considered as hidden layer. So yes, convolution and pooling operations happens in hidden layers.

Comment: I know and it should be like this but I read the post in which I took this photo and it claimed that after doing this whole operations we then feed the output(FC layer) to our network and it would be our network input ! (As you can see in the photo) and I think it's misleading.In other hand we say in FC layer every input is connected to every output (in other layers they don't) so if it's true all the network seemed to be FC layer !
Please make it clear to me